# Connection error in Azure Stream Analytics with DocumentDB (MongoDB API) as sink

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I configured Azure Stream Analytics to send my messages to DocumentDB (CosmosDB). This was working fine. 
But when I switched to DocumentDB with MongoDB API I run into a connection error. This error is raised when I send a message, so my stream was running till it got a message.

> Message: Could not initialize connection to DocumentDB database [PdM-DocumentDB-002] collection [devicedata].

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB API based CosmosDB collections are not supported with Azure Stream Analytics. We will keep you posted in case we [plan to] add support for it.